# QOS bandwidth error in LB-Link Router

Tags: wireless-router, wireless-access-point, bandwidth, internet-speed, qos

I'm trying to limit my phone bandwidth in LB-Link Router to ***(24mb/s upload, 49mb/s download)***
LB-Link uses kb/s, according to Google, ***(49mb/s = 392000 kb/s)***, but I get the following error

> "The input is illegal, please enter a value between 0 and 99999"

which means they only accept 5 numbers in the value.
[image: QOS manager]
[image: error]

Comment: It looks like it's complaining that you didn't enter a range of times of day for this rule to be in effect. They suggest you enter zeroes if you want this in effect at all times.

Comment: Also, I'm nervous about the fact they use KB in caps. Some people use capital KB to mean KiB ( = KibiBytes = 1024's of 8-bit bytes). But then again, network speeds are usually measured in kilo/mega/giga bits per second, not KibiBytes, so maybe they do mean kilobits instead of KibiBytes. This product seems so low-quality, I wouldn't be surprised if it's sloppy in this area.

Comment: @Spiff thanks for your answers, unfortunately, i'm still getting the same error even after filling that range of times, also this brand is trash because of its price (25$ up to 300mb/s)